# import xlsx to mysql with phpexcel selecting all columns

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Need some help with this code.
When I import the xlsx file the merged cells are treated as 2 rows.
How can I change it to select col by col in a way that the merged cells will be splited and treated as single columns (eg: A+B+C with 'some info' -> colA with 'some info', colB with 'null/empty', colC with 'null/empty').

The code:

```
<?php
@session_start();   
//-->
$file = $_SESSION['file'];
$sheet = $_POST['sheet'];
//-->
//--> Include PHPExcel and MySQLi db */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '\Classes2\DB.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '\Classes2\PHPExcel.php';

//--> Create DB object
use DB\MySQLi;


//--> Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet($sheet);

$dataArr = array();

foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
   $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex();
   $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
   $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(True); 
   foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
      $colIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($cell->getColumn());
      $val = $cell->getValue();
      $dataArr[$rowIndex][$colIndex] = $val;

   } 
}

unset($dataArr[1]); 

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'user';
$password = '´pass';
$database = 'base';

$db = new MySQLi($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

foreach($dataArr as $val){
   $query = $db->query("INSERT INTO excel SET eid = '" . $db->escape($val['1']) . "',name = '" . $db->escape($val['2']) . "', email = '" . $db->escape($val['3']) . "', dob = '" . $db->escape($val['4']) . "'");
}                                       

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if any individual cell is part of a merge range using:

```
$cell->isInMergeRange();
```

which returns a boolean identifying whether or not the cell is part of a merge range or not.

Only the top-leftmost cell in a merge range contains the value, and you can identify if a cell within a merge range is that value cell using

```
$cell->isMergeRangeValueCell();
```

So check whether the cell is part of a merge range, if not then you want its value; and if it is, check f it's the merge range value cell, and you want its value if it is, otherwise discard it

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer, makes all the sense. Just a litle help... In my code, where and/or what should I change to make it work with your example and explanation? Thank you.